# Sharing directive between apps in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to serve a directive from a `/common/` folder in my project when I have an `app1` and `app2` folders as siblings of /common/ that will ideally serve the same directive. With partials and services, it was easy to just include them with the correct path - but how do I use the same directive in two different apps?

I'm getting stuck where I need to declare what module the directive belongs to - but I don't want to do that because it can change based on the app (`app1.directive()` and `app2.directive()` etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. Here is how it's done:

When you're building the service:

```
angular.module('app.directiveName').directive(...);
```

In the app you need to declare it in the dependencies:

`['app.directiveName']`

Lastly, in the app, you need to include the module in the app:

```
angular.module('app.directiveName', []);
```